# SQL Replace Commas in the a row of a table

Tags: sql

I have table `test( ID Numeric(11,0), report varchar(255) )`
and data looks below

```
1   ,Age,,,,,,family_status,,,,,,
2   ,,,,,,,,retaliation,hostile environment,,,,
3   ,,,,,,,,,,,,,
4   ,,,,,,,,retaliation,,,,,
5   ,,,,,,,,,hostile environment,,,,
6   ,Age,,,,,,,,,,,,
7   ,,,,national_origin,,,,,,,,,
8   Sex,,,,,,,,,,,,,
9   ,,,,national_origin,,disability,,retaliation,,,,,
10  Sex,,,,,,,,retaliation,,,,,
11  ,,,,,,,,
```

and i would like to update this table by replacing or using any other data scribing to  remove extra commas so that data looks

```
1   Age,family_status
2   retaliation,hostile environment
3   
4   retaliation
5   hostile environment
6   Age
7   national_origin,
8   Sex
9   national_origin,disability,retaliation
10  Sex,retaliation
11
```

i try to use the below statement but not sure how to loop through so that it will check and remove all the commas

```
UPDATE table test SET report = replace(report , ',,', ',')
```

Comment: What platform are you using, on some platforms you can use a recursive CTE

Comment: This could be better done in a full program written in C# or Java or whatever technology you choose, are you restricted to do it in the database?

Answer (score 2):

If you are just doing this as a one off task (rather than a scripted process you expect to use repeatedly) you could always just run this query repeatedly until you get 0 rows updated

```
UPDATE table test SET report = replace(report , ',,', ',')
WHERE report like '%,,%'
```

If you need to do this over and over, or put it in a program I recommend using your procedural (non SQL code) to do the replace where you have better text manipulation commands.

If you aren't thrilled with that, check out [this blog article](http://improvingsoftware.com/2011/03/21/replacing-multiple-spaces-in-a-string-with-a-single-space-in-sql/) I wrote on a similar problem of replacing repeating spaces from a string.

Comment: Wow ...Thanks John iteratively solution faster than recursive